# iTunesConnectへアプリのアップロードでバイナリデータが消える。

Tags: ios, xcode

みなさま。お疲れ様です。

さっそくですが質問です。
iPadアプリを作成しXcodeにてiTunesConnectにバイナリデータをアップロードしました。
結果は成功と出て、iTunesConnectで確認すると「プレリリース」「ビルド」にアップロードしたバージョンのバイナリデータが処理中になって表示されました。
しかし、数分すると先ほどまで処理中となっていたバイナリデータが消え、どこにも見当たらなくなってしまいました。
また、「バージョン」での「ビルド」選択画面にも、以前にリジェクトされた５つは表示されているのですが、新しいバイナリデータは表示されていません。

同じBuildの物を再度Xcodeで「Upload to App Store」すると、既にアップロードされているとエラーになります。
数回Buildバージョンを1.0.0->1.0.1->1.0.2と番号を上げればアップロードは成功しますが、iTunesConnectでは同じようにバイナリデータが1,2分で消えてしまいます。

原因を探して色々と試してはいるのですが、解決できなかったので投稿させていただきました。

アップロードまでの手順は、Edit SchemesでBuild ConfigurationをReleasesに変更。
その後は「Product」から「Archive」「Validate]「Upload to App Store」でアップロードしました。

Xcode6からXcode7へ以降したのですがここで何か間違ったのかも。。。

みなさまのお力をお貸しください！！
よろしくお願いします！

// 9月25日　追記
本日、iTunesConnectにアクセスしたところ、iTunesConnectのバージョンアップに伴ってか、昨日アップロードしたのに消えてしまった物が「処理中」と表示されるようになっていました。

// 9月28日　追記
無事、審査に提出することが出来ました。
iTunesConnectからバイナリが表示されていなかった問題はiTunesConnectのバージョンアップが原因だったのかな？と思います。
契約の内容の更新についての同意もまだ途中までだったみたいなので、きちんと最後まで完了しました。
Xcode7に更新してGoogleMaps for iOS を使用していたのが原因？でずっと処理中のままでしたが、Xcode6.4で提出したらあっさり通りました。
Xcode7の時にUpload to App Storeをした際に出たエラー「ERROR ITMS-90535 ,CFBundleExecutable関係のエラーが出た時に「GoolgeMaps.bundle」などの「Executable file」を削除してしまった事が、「処理中」が終わらない原因だったと思います。

この場をお借りして、ご回答してくださった皆様にお礼を申し上げます。
また、お力添えをしていただけると大変助かります。

ありがとうございました！

Comment: 念のため確認ですが、バージョン番号は上げていますでしょうか？
通信エラー等でアップロードに途中で失敗した場合でも、同一のバージョン番号は二度と使用できません。
1.0.0→1.0.1 のようにバージョン番号を上げて再ビルド、再アップロードしてください。

Comment: Stato様。さっそくの回答ありがとうございます！すいません、質問内容に状況をしっかり記入出来ていませんでした！バージョンもきちんと上げておりますが、Xcode側では成功となるのですが、全く同じ状況になってしまいます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

少し前に、従来まで、別立てで合った、iOS,Mac-OS,Safariのデベロッパープログラムが、一本化されましたが、それに伴い、登録情報の更新（新規に有効となった開発プログラムの税、支払条項）およびアグリーメントの同意が求められていますが、それを放置したりしていませんか？
　放置していると、新規のAppはもちろん、Appのアップデートも、前から有効な開発プログラムでも、出来ません。

Comment: kmugitani様。ご回答ありがとうございます！
iTunesConnectにログインした時に警告がページ上部に出ていたので、更新し、表示されなくなっていたので大丈夫だとは思うのですが、「Contracts In Process」がSetUpのボタンのままなので、まだ完了していなかったてことなんでしょうか？

今朝確認したら、iTunesConnectがアップデートされていて、昨日消えていたビルドをチェクしてみましたら「Upload to App Store」で上げた物が「処理中」として表示されていました。

iTunesConnectのアップデートが問題だったんでしょうか...？
今はこの処理中が本当に完了するのか見守るだけです...

kmugitani様からご指摘いただきました登録情報の更新を再度見なおして見ようと思います。

Answer (score 1):

一般的なネットワーク環境であれば問題ないので可能性は低いですが、
一部の企業のネットワーク回線の場合、
Appleのサーバーにipaをアップロードする際のUDP通信がファイアーウォールにて一部ブロックされてしまい、
まれにアップロード出来ない場合があります。

その場合、モバイルルータ等、別の回線に切り替えるとアップロードに成功します。

Comment: Takayoshi Sato様。ご回答ありがとうございます。
今朝、確認してみたところ昨日は表示されていなかったにも関わらず、「処理中」としてアップロードしたバイナリが表示されていました。

通信環境によってアップロードできない事があるというは凄く勉強になりました。

Answer (score 0):

アップロードしてからiTunes Connectに反映されるまでに時間差があるように思われます。
私のアプリも今朝アップロードして4時間くらい経ちますが、まだ処理中です。
（昨日は「(処理中)」も表示されてなかった気がしますが、忘れた頃に反映されてました）

Comment: Rui S様。ご回答ありがとうございます。

今朝、確認したところiTunesConnectのバージョンアップのおかげなのか、せいなのか、無事に表示されるようにはなりました！
しかし、私も半日たった今でもまだ処理中なんですよね。

Answer (score 0):

バイナリを送信後に警告は出ていませんか？

黄色に黒の`！`は無視できる警告なのでストアに反映が可能です。
ですが、
赤色に白の`×`や`！`はアップロードに失敗しています。
失敗の例としては
・アップロード時に過去のバージョンよりバージョン番号が新しくなっていない
・アイコン画像が正しくセットされていない
などなど……

成功した後、
NEXTを押すことで「パッケージをiTunes Storeにアップロードしました」となり送信が完了します。
送信が完了してから反映までに、早い時は5分ほど、遅い時は1時間くらい掛かる時があります。
もし、気になる用でしたら[問い合わせ](https://developer.apple.com/jp/contact/phone.php)してみる事をお勧めします。

Comment: Sieg様　回答ありがとうございます！
今朝、iTunesConnectを確認してみたところ、iTunesConnectのバージョンアップに伴ってなのか、昨日アップロードしたのに消えてしまっていたバイナリが表示されて「処理中」となっていました。
何時間も処理中のままなので、凄く不安ですが昨日で複数のバイナリをアップロードしてしまった為なのかな？と楽観的ですけど思っています。
電話での問い合わせは初めて知りました！昨日、サポートにメールしたんですがこれを知っていれば...

貴重なお時間を割いてのご回答ありがとうございます！